# Summing a series of numbers using reduce

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, for-loop, sum

## Problem

I'm making an AJAX call to fetch data and iterating over a series of items with a for loop. I've gotten to the point where I have all the numbers with `bids[i].Bids`, but I'm looking to sum all the values using `reduce()`

I've tried the snippet below, but it doesn't sum all the numbers `ie. 0, 50, 500, 250, 500, 25` as they appear in separate lines when I `console.log()` them and are not in an array?

### scripts.js

```
    /*-------------------------------------
    STEP ONE: PLACE BID
    --------------------------------------*/

  $.ajax({
   url: "https://sheetsu.com/apis/4a8eceba",
   method: "GET",
   dataType: "json"
 }).then(function(spreadsheet) {


  /*-------------------------------------
  SUM BIDS IN ARRAY
  --------------------------------------*/

  var bids = spreadsheet.result;

  for (i = 0; i < bids.length; i++) {
    var allBids = bids[i].Bids; // List of all the bids
    console.log(allBids);
  }
```

**Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) I see this example to sum all the values of an array.**

```
var total = [0, 1, 2, 3].reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
});
// total == 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have an array of *objects* you need to modify reduce function a little to sum `Bids` properties of individual objects:

```
var bids = spreadsheet.result;

var total = bids.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev + curr.Bids;
}, 0);
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the numbers `005050025050025` all lumped together

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, why do you want loop?

Comment: I guess I'm wondering if you can explain in more detail what the reduce function is doing as what I'm getting is a string of numbers printed to the console, as opposed to those numbers getting summed. One change I had tried to make in my previous code was to change `totalBids` to `var totalBids = parseInt(bids[i].Bids)` inside the for loop

Comment: So right now, I'm basically getting a string of the numbers `005050025050025` as opposed the numbers summed.